# ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER SCHEDULED JOB

Tags: oracle, scheduled-tasks, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am planning to use SQL developer scheduled jobs for our daily extract.
Assuming that I already have a scheduled job (SQL query), where or how can I see the extracted data?

Comment: Jobs are database objects, sql developer is just the gui you use to develop and manage them. Your job will run some plsql code (most likely), and that code could write files to a directory via UTL_FILE...but that's your task to write that code.

Comment: You could do an OS job to launch sqlcl to connect and spool the data out to a local file in whatever format and location you desire as well. Who do want to the work, the server or client?

Answer (score -1):

please following the link for tutorial create job sql developer.

scott

https://www.foxinfotech.in/2018/10/how-to-schedule-a-job-oracle-sql-developer.html